# Image auto-cropping, issue with borders

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm talking photo in my application. After I take it, on next screen in layout I want it be automatically cropped like in image.
[image]
But I'm constantly lose the boundaries of the photo and I have strange borders (indicated by RED in the image).

Here is my code:

```
Android code 
private void NewElement_OnDrawBitmap(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ViewGroup != null)
            {
                //get the subview
                Android.Views.View subView = ViewGroup.GetChildAt(0);
                int width = subView.Width;
                int height = subView.Height;

                //create and draw the bitmap
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
                Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                ViewGroup.Draw(c);

                //save the bitmap to file
                bytes = SaveBitmapToFile(b);
            }
        }


iOS code
 UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(this.Bounds.Size, true, 0);
            this.Layer.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());
            var img = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
            using (NSData imageData = img.AsPNG())
            {
                bytes = new Byte[imageData.Length];
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
            }
        private byte[] SaveBitmapToFile(Bitmap bm)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bm.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
}
```

Comment: Try to set `Aspect="AspectFit"` of Image .

Comment: Thank you. but I did it already.

Comment: You could share a sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: It's card to devide it from project, might be you need some other part of code? @LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: You could create a new sample which contains the issue .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT here you can check sources [link](https://dropmefiles.com/VWtSf)

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT just follow up, have you treied to download sources?

Comment: I could not access the link , you could upload it to github .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT here is a link to github [link](https://github.com/wearesputnik/test.git)

Comment: @FedorPetrenko Thanks for sharing the sample, I will check that.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT have you checked the code?

Comment: @FedorPetrenko Hi, I have checked the project. However, can't reproduce the phenomenon as your said. Do you mean that want the selected photo be cropped by the 
range of `FrameVIew` which from the sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your shared code, you're not doing any cropping, so your app just put your origin picture into the view, and the border you mentioned, is probably the background of your view.
And your project code, I saw you added

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(b, 0, 0, (98 * width) / 100, (82 * height) / 100);
```

Yes this is cropping the picture, but this just crop the image from top-left corner to 98% width and 82% height. much like

[image]

If you want to crop the picture into a square focused in center, you can simply:

```
int offset = (height - width) / 2;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(b, 0, offset, width, height- offset);
```

But if you want to do more operations on Image like move/zoom... and then crop, I'd like to suggest you turn to existing solutions like [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Transformations-Guide#croptransformation) or [Syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/image-editor/crop). Or you'll have to calculate all the move/zoom data to do the crop.